# Is every covering space associated to a "principal" covering space? Can they be classified?

Tags: fibre-bundles, principal-bundles, covering-spaces

Every fiber bundle is associated to a principal bundle with the same structure group. A covering space is just a fiber bundle with a discrete fiber, and hence a structure group $G$ that is a (subgroup of a) permutation group. To every covering space $E$ we can therefore associate a principal bundle $P$ whose fiber is $G$, and conversely every covering space with structure group $G$ can be recovered as the associated bundle $P\times_G F$ of some principal $G$-bundle given a $G$-set $F$.

Clearly $P$ is also a covering space. Principal covering spaces are exactly what's called "regular" covering spaces, i.e. ones where the group of deck transformations acts transitively on the fiber, so that $\mathrm{Aut}(P)=G$. This is completely analogous to general principal $G$-bundles, which have the global symmetry group $G$ acting freely.

Now we have two classification results:

**Classification of $G$-bundles:** each principal $G$-bundle can be identified with a functor that establishes an equivalence between $G$-spaces and associated bundles, thereby providing a classification of all fiber bundles with structure group $G$.

**Classification of covering spaces:** the universal covering of $B$ is identified with a functor that establishes an equivalence between $\pi_1(B)$-sets and all coverings of $B$.

These look very similar, except $\pi_1(B)$ is *not* the structure group of a covering map as a bundle, and the classifying functor is given by the universal covering, not just any regular (principal) one. So what is the relationship between regular coverings and universal coverings? Can the classification of covering spaces be restated in terms of some classification of regular coverings (with a fixed structure group)?

I found a lengthy discussion along these lines in Tommo tom Dieck's algebraic topology book (he even introduces the concept of a "universal $G$-principal covering"), but the final conclusion is still very murky to me. How can a universal covering be anything other than $\pi_1(B)$-principal?

The most similar question on Stackexchange seems to be [Can every covering space be obtained from a principal $G$-bundle with $G$ discrete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487174/can-every-covering-space-be-obtained-from-a-principal-g-bundle-with-g-discre), but the answer there only shows that not every covering space is principal (which is obvious anyway).

Comment: You'll need to be more specific regarding what you want "principal" to mean in this situation, and how that might vary from whatever definition of covering space you are currently using.

Comment: @RyanBudney how so? I think it means the same thing as for any other fiber bundle: a bundle with a fiber wise free and transitive global action of $G$. These are exactly the same things as regular coverings.

Comment: One potential source of confusion in discussing this is that a fiber bundle does not determine something called its structure group. Rather, given a group $G$, and given an action of $G$ on a space $F$, one can discuss "bundles with fiber $F$ and structure group $G$", meaning fiber bundles whose fibers are homeomorphic to $F$ and which are equipped with families of local trivializations such that the comparison maps, or clutching functions, relating two local trivializations, take values in $G$.

Comment: It is not that $G$ is acting on all the fibers. For example, a rank $n$ vector bundle is not furnished with an action of$GL_n(R)$.

Comment: Relatedly, in understanding covering spaces one should distinguish between the action of the fundamental group of the base and the action of the deck transformations on all the fibers.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie I understand that. We can always take $G$ to be the entire group of permutations of points of the fiber. I've edited the question with more details.

Comment: Even if we take $G$ to be the entire permutation group, this still has no direct relation to the $\pi_1(B)$-action that the standard classification theorem uses.

Comment: @level1807: just look at the comments and Tom's answer.  People don't appear to understand what your question is.  If you know the theory of covering spaces, you should probably be able to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If $B$ is a nice (for example locally contractible) path-connected based space then principal $G$-covering spaces $P\to B$ are classified by homomorphisms $\alpha: \pi_1(B)\to G$. In the case when $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, this is the "universal" covering space $U\to B$; the total space $U$ is simply connected. If $\alpha$ is merely surjective and $N$ is its kernel, then $P$ is the usual (regular)covering space of $B$ corresponding to the (normal) subgroup $N\subset \pi_1(B)$. It can be described as $U/N$. (I prefer to write the $G$-action on a principal bundle as a right action.)

If $G$ acts (on the left) on some set $F$, then any principal $G$-covering space $P\to B$ determines an "associated bundle" $P\times_GF$ with fiber $F$. If we are specifically interested in connected covering spaces, then we should assume that the action of $G$ on $F$ is transitive, so that $F$ can be viewed as $G/H$ for some subgroup $H\subset G$ and the covering space becomes $P/H$. In the special case when the principal covering space that we are using is the universal one, then this is the usual covering space of $B$ corresponding to the subgroup $H\subset G=\pi_1(B)$.

On the other hand, if $E\to B$ is just any covering space, say connected and with $n$ points in each fiber, corresponding to some subgroup $K\subset \pi_1(B)$ of index $n$, then we might take the structure group to be the symmetric group $S_n$. The relevant principal covering space will not be connected, in general.

The action of $\pi_1(B)$ on the fiber over the basepoint yields a homomorphism $h:\pi_1(B)\to S_n$ (once we have picked a definite bijection between that fiber and $\{1,\dots ,n\}$), whose image, a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, is isomorphic to $\pi_1(B)/ker(h)$. We have the option of taking this image, rather than the full $S_n$, as structure group. Note that the subgroup $ker(h)$ is the intersection of the conjugates of $K$. The principal covering space that arises here is connected.

I'm not sure if this answers your question at all.